# Criterion for determining when uniform convergence of multivariate convex functions is convex

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose we have a sequence of convex multivariate functions

$f_a(\vec{v}): S \to \Bbb R$

defined on some open convex subset $S$ of $\Bbb R^n$, which converge uniformly to some limit function $f_\infty(\vec{v})$.

**Question**: What criteria exist to establish that $f_\infty(\vec{v})$ is also convex?

I think [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956735/convex-functions-converge-uniformly-then-their-derivatives-too) shows this need not be true in general, but is there some simple criterion for when this is true?

FYI, while I have searched and found a lot of questions about uniform convergence and convex functions, I haven't found a question addressing such criteria in the multivariate case. Apologies if this has been asked already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointwise limits of convex functions are convex (by definition) and hence uniform limits too. The post you have referred to is irrelevant to this question.

If $S$ is a convex subset of a vector space $V$ over the reals then a function $f:S \to \mathbb R$ is called convex if $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ whenever $x,y \in S$ and $0 \leq t \leq 1$. If $f_n(tx+(1-t)y) \leq tf_n(x)+(1-t)f_n(y)$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise to $f$ we can simply let $n \to \infty$ to get $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$.

Comment: You're saying that, effectively, given *any* sequence of convex functions that converges pointwise to some limit, that limit is guaranteed to also be convex, *even in the multivariate case*?

Comment: Yes, that is surely true.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia See the explanation I has added to my answer.