# Do subdifferentials of a uniformly converging sequence of convex functions converge pointwise?

Tags: convex-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Consider a sequence of continuous convex functions, $f_n,f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, compact. The sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Does $\nabla f_n$ converge to $\nabla f$ pointwise, wherever $\nabla f$ exists?

I am confused because [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0362546X9390040Y) and [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01207197) seem to suggest that the answer is yes (See footnote), but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956735/convex-functions-converge-uniformly-then-their-derivatives-too?noredirect=1&lq=1) (See the second answer) seems to provide a counterexample.

What am I missing?

Edit: The following theorem in Rockafellar's Convex Analysis also seems to imply pointwise convergence of derivatives wherever they exist (Note the "Moreover" part).

THEOREM 24.5 (Rockafellar, 1997, p. 233). Let $f$ be a convex function on $R^n$, and let $C$ be an open convex set on which $f$ is finite. Let $f_1, f_2, \ldots$, be a sequence of convex functions finite on $C$ and converging pointwise to f on $C$. Let $x \in C$, and let $x_1, x_2, \ldots$, be a sequence of points in $C$ converging to $x$. Then, for any $y \in R^n$ and any sequence $y_1, y_2, \ldots$, converging to $y$, one has
$$
\limsup _{i \rightarrow \infty} f_i^{\prime}\left(x_i ; y_i\right) \leq f^{\prime}(x ; y) .
$$
Moreover, given any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an index $i_0$ such that
$$
\partial f_i\left(x_i\right) \subset \partial f(x)+\varepsilon B, \quad \forall i \geq i_0,
$$
where $B$ is the Euclidean unit ball of $R^n$.

Footnote: The first paper mentions this right at the first paragraph. In the second paper, towards the beginning of the second page, the author says,"Roughly speaking, a sequence of convex functions converges if and only if the sequence of their "derivatives" converges, too!" This is right after he gives the precise statement of this result, starting at the bottom of the first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence of subdifferentials is usually meant in the sense of *graphical convergence*, which is not the same thing as pointwise convergence. The convergence mentioned by the theorem of Attouch refers to graphical convergence, whereas (I believe) the counterexample demonstrates that pointwise convergence may fail. The distinction is a bit technical, so I'll just point to a really great reference with formal definitions, motivating examples, comparisons, and theoretical guarantees (e.g., when one type of convergence can imply another).

[*Variational Analysis*, by Rockafellar and Wets](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ertr/papers/rtr169-VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf),

- Chapter 5.E (page 166): these notions of convergence and their differences
- Theorem 12.35: The convergence result by Attouch.
- p. 239 - discussion on pointwise convergence

To quote the book,

> Graphical convergence doesn’t generally imply pointwise convergence, and pointwise convergence doesn’t generally imply graphical convergence. A sequence of mappings $S^\nu$ can even be such that both its graphical limit and its
> pointwise limit exist, but the two are different! An example of this phenomenon
> is displayed in Figure 5–9.

Comment: Thank you so much for the ref! I'm going through it and I do realize they're normally not implied by each other. However, I also found a result in Rockafellar, which seems to claim pt-wise conv. I've edited the question to add it. Maybe here there are additional assumptions which make it valid? Unless my understanding of pointwise convergence is yet again mistaken here.

Comment: Ah, nice -- yeah this result is close, but to me it looks like it only gives us pointwise convergence to an *epsilon-subdifferential*: $\partial f(x)+\varepsilon B$ here means all $u+v$ where $u\in\partial f(x)$ and $\|v\|\leq \varepsilon$. As compared to the typical subdifferential (which requires $\varepsilon=0$), this notion of the epsilon-subgradient behaves much nicer when dealing with pointwise convergence.

Comment: oh I just realized the quantifier -- *for every* epsilon. This might actually show it, since your question already assumes existence of the pointwise derivative!

Comment: So that would mean pointwise convergence at all points of differentiability of $f$, i.e. a.e., right? Because at those points $x$, $\partial f(x)$ is a singleton, say $z$, so $\partial f_i(x)$ is contained in an $\epsilon$-ball around $z$? Also, I think I figured out the reconciliation between this and the counterexample: The latter picks a point of non-differentiability of the limiting function. Do you think that's correct?

Comment: To answer to your last comment, I didn't assume differentiability, i.e. existence of gradient everywhere. But convex functions are ae differentiable, so they'll exist a.e. and I think the Rockefeller result shows pointwise convergence at those points, i.e. a.e. convergence (weaker than pointwise).